# Confusion with Null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm pretty new to flutter and because of the null safety feature I've been getting a lot of errors from a code that will run perfectly fine in Java or other langs. For example this-

```
int ? i;
  var icecreamFlavours = ['chocolate', 'vanilla', 'orange'];
  icecreamFlavours.forEach((item) {
    i++; //This is where I get the error
    print('We have the $item flavour');
  });
```

**My Error Message**

`Error: Operator '+' cannot be called on 'int?' because it is potentially null.`

`i++;`

`Error: A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int?'.`

`i++;`

Comment: What is `i++` supposed to do on the first iteration of the loop?  Make `i` non-nullable and initialize it first: `int i = 0;`.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do either `i++` or `i+=1` on a nullable variable, because the reason is simple, null variable can have null values which will make increment no sense.

In addition to this, you can't even do `i!++` or `i!+=1` even if you are sure that `i` is not null. There is an open issue for this https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1113

So for now you can do this `i = i! + 1`

Update:
For `i = i! + 1` to work you need to be sure about `i` not being null. So it's better to initialise/assign `i` with some value before using it.

Comment: `i = i! + 1` won't work because  `i` is never initialized to a non-null value, and it therefore will throw an exception on the first iteration.  The better fix in this case is to initialize `i` to a non-null value.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for your input. Answer updated.